# Mostrar F(n) da sequencia de fibonacci em Algoritmo

Tags: algoritmo, while, visualg, fibonnaci

Preciso saber o ultimo termo da sequência de Fibonacci, já fiz para mostrar todos os termos, mas preciso que mostre o ultimo
Estou usando o VisualG

```
Algoritmo "Fibonacci"
Var
   v1, v2, v3, limite, cont: inteiro
Inicio
      escreval("Digite um limite:")
      leia(limite)
      v1 <- -1
      v2 <- 1
      cont <- 0
      
      enquanto cont< limite faca
            v3 <- v1 + v2
            v1<- v2
            v2 <- v3
            escreva(v3)
            cont <- cont+1
      fimenquanto
Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que todo seu código está correto, pra imprimir apenas o último valor, você só precisa tirar o comando de dentro do *loop* e colocá-lo após o laço. Com isso, você só imprimirá o resultado final:

```
...
      enquanto cont< limite faca
            v3 <- v1 + v2
            v1<- v2
            v2 <- v3
            cont <- cont+1
      fimenquanto

      escreva(v3)
...
```